# What tools can I use for a WPF client-server application with database?

Tags: wpf, client-server

I need my WPF desktop app to allow multiple users to log in and change all sorts of parameters, so I need a database and some form of communication between a server and clients. But I am completely new to communication between computers and most of what I found are examples for localhost, while I need a server that others computers can connect to. Moreover, I'm not sure where the database would find itself in all of this, from what I read it should be on the server computer, but I'm not sure how that works.

The tool I found the most in my searches is WCF, would it accomplish what I mentioned above, and how? And what other alternatives do I have?

Comment: WCF with Azure good to go.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will give it a look.